# React JS - Update user information on select value change

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

**I have** a component that is doing rather a lot - possibly not the best practice but this is my first react app so once I have everything working I will probably go back to refactor bits and pieces.

I have a constructor setting up state.

I have a componentDidMount that fetches JSON from an API.

I have a render function that sets up some variables and produces some JSX code, this returns a table with client data taken from the json api and includes a select menu with options loaded from the api.

I have an event handler that runs onChange when the user changes the select value.

**What currently happens** when the select value is changed to (for example) Team 1, then all of the selects change to 'Team 1' instead of just that 1 record.

**What I am trying to do** is just update the 1 record but then also be able to return the User.ID along with the new select value (for the 1 record) so I can then update the API (I know how to post the data back it's just getting the correct values to post).

My code below:

```
import React from 'react';

class GetUnassignedUsers extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data:{unassignedUsers:[],teams:[]},
            selectValue: '8'
        };
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        fetch("http://localhost/dashboard/?action=unassignedUsers.getUnassingedUsers", {
            credentials: 'same-origin'
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then( (json) => {
            this.setState({
                data: json
            });
        });
    }
    handleChange (event) {
        alert(this.state);
        this.setState({
            selectValue: event.target.value
        });
    }
    render () {
        let unassignedUsers = this.state.data.unassignedUsers;
        let teams = this.state.data.teams;
        let availableTeams = teams.map(function (team) {
            return (
                <option value={team.id}>{team.team_name}</option>
            )
        });
        let select = (
            <select value={this.state.selectValue} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
                {availableTeams}
            </select>
        );
        let rows = unassignedUsers.map(function (user) {
            return (
                <tr>
                    <td>{user.ID}</td>
                    <td>{user.dateCreated}</td>
                    <td>{user.company}</td>
                    <td>{user.email}</td>
                    <td>{user.contactName}</td>
                    <td>{user.quoteDomain}</td>
                    <td>{user.InvoicePostCode}</td>
                    <td>
                        {select}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            )
        });
        return (
            <tbody>
                {rows}
            </tbody>
        );
    }
}

export default GetUnassignedUsers;
```

Comment: u r using only one select, not getting this line `when the select value is changed to (for example) Team 1, then all of the selects change to 'Team 1' instead of just that 1 record.` could u explain more ??

Comment: Yeah, I too can only see 1 select?

Comment: i think i got it, he uses one select because select is same for all table rows, when he changes any one all of them get changed, he has to use separate select for all table rows.

Comment: By the way, you better to add `key` property to each `option`: `<option value={team.id} key={team.id}>{team.team_name}</option>`. This will prevent re-render issues and console warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create the `select` for all the rows then u need to create them separately for all rows, and a separate `state` variable is required to store the changed value, try this it will work.

Check `jsfiddle` for working example: https://jsfiddle.net/hmm47qLg/

`selectValue` will be an array, each value will store the `state` of each `select`-

```
constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
        data:{unassignedUsers:[],teams:[]},
        selectValue: []
    };
}
```

Use this `render` method, it will create `select` for each row-

```
render () {
    let unassignedUsers = this.state.data.unassignedUsers;
    let teams = this.state.data.teams;
    let availableTeams = teams.map((team,i)=> {
        return (
            <option key={i} value={team.id}>{team.team_name}</option>
        )
    });
    //let select = (
    //    <select value={this.state.selectValue} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
    //        {availableTeams}
    //    </select>
    //);
    let rows = unassignedUsers.map((user, i)=> {
        return (
            <tr key={i}>
                <td>{user.ID}</td>
                <td>{user.dateCreated}</td>
                <td>{user.company}</td>
                <td>{user.email}</td>
                <td>{user.contactName}</td>
                <td>{user.quoteDomain}</td>
                <td>{user.InvoicePostCode}</td>
                <td>
                    <select value={this.state.selectValue[i]} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, user, i)}>
                        {availableTeams}
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        )
    });
    return (
        <table>
            <tbody>
                {rows}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```

Inside `onChange` method pass the user `object` and the `index` of the row-

```
handleChange(user, index, e){
    console.log('user', user, e.target.value);
    let selectValue = this.state.selectValue;
    selectValue[index] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({selectValue});
}
```

In `onChange` method u have the complete `user` object, if you want to send the data to server, u can write the `api` call here.

Comment: Great answer, the only thing I need for this step is the select value being user.team_id - although when I put <select value={user.team_id}... I select a different option and although I get the correct values in my console log it doesn't update on the dom, it just goes back to the team_id value.

Comment: in that case `selectValue` is not required, n use these line in change event:
`let data = this.state.data;
data.unassignedUsers[index].team_id = e.target.value;
this.setState({data);` directly use the `user.team_id` as the value of `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (excuse any errors, haven't tested it)

```
import React from 'react';

class GetUnassignedUsers extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data:{unassignedUsers:[],teams:[]},
            selectValue: '8'
        };
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        fetch("http://localhost/dashboard/?action=unassignedUsers.getUnassingedUsers", {
            credentials: 'same-origin'
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then( (json) => {
            this.setState({
                data: json
            });
        });
    }
    handleChange (index, event) {
        alert(this.state);
        this.state.data.unassignedUsers[index].selectValue = event.target.value;
        this.state.forceUpdate();

    }
    render () {
        let unassignedUsers = this.state.data.unassignedUsers;
        let teams = this.state.data.teams;
        let availableTeams = teams.map(function (team) {
            return (
                <option value={team.id}>{team.team_name}</option>
            )
        });
        let select = (

        );
        let rows = unassignedUsers.map(function (user, index) {
            return (
                <tr>
                    <td>{user.ID}</td>
                    <td>{user.dateCreated}</td>
                    <td>{user.company}</td>
                    <td>{user.email}</td>
                    <td>{user.contactName}</td>
                    <td>{user.quoteDomain}</td>
                    <td>{user.InvoicePostCode}</td>
                    <td>
                        <select value={user.selectValue} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, index)}>
                            { availableTeams }
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            )
        });
        return (
            <tbody>
                {rows}
            </tbody>
        );
    }
}

export default GetUnassignedUsers;
```